# Solving Non-Homogenous Recurrence Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations, cubics

I was interested in Solution of this **Non-Homogenous Recurrence Relation**

$f(n)=f(n-1) + f(n-3) + 1$

The Base conditions are:
$f(0)=1$
$f(1)=2$
$f(2)=3$

Kindly help me in solving this **Recurrence Relation**, by any known method.

Comment: **Hint** Make $f_n=g_n+k$ and find $k$ such that there on more constant in the equation for $g_n$. For the cubic, don't you know how to get them when you already have one of them ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have solved cubic using Numerical Methods. Unable to factorize and get complex roots.

Comment: Divide the cubic by $(x-x_1)$ to get a quadratic equation which is easy to solve for the complex roots (which are conjugate).

Comment: Are you sure the problem is stated correctly?  The solution doesn't appear to have any nice form.  The generating function turns out to be $1/((1-z)(1-z-z^3))$.

Comment: **Update** : I was more interested in inequality part. This has been solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4341789/963109)

Answer (score 2):

Let $g_n = f_n + 1$ so that
\begin{align}
g_n &= g_{n−1} + g_{n−3} &&\text{for $n\ge3$} \\ 
g_0 &= 2 \\
g_1 &= 3 \\
g_2 &= 4
\end{align}
Let $G(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0} g_n z^n$ be the generating function.  The recurrence relation and boundary conditions imply that
$$G(z) = 2z^0+3z^1+4z^2+\sum_{n\ge 3} (g_{n−1} + g_{n−3}) z^n 
= 2+3z+4z^2 + z (G(z)-2-3z) + z^3 G(z),$$
so
$$G(z) = \frac{2+z+z^2}{1-z-z^3},$$
which yields
$$F(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} f_n z^n = \sum_{n\ge 0} (g_n-1) z^n = \frac{2+z+z^2}{1-z-z^3} - \frac{1}{1-z} = \frac{1}{(1-z)(1-z-z^3)}.$$

See https://oeis.org/A077868.  The linked entry https://oeis.org/A000930 for the shifted sequence $f_{n+3}-1$ has this formula:

```
a(n) = floor(d*c^n + 1/2) where c is the real root of x^3-x^2-1 and d is the real root of 31*x^3-31*x^2+9*x-1 (c = 1.465571... = A092526 and d = 0.611491991950812...). - Benoit Cloitre, Nov 30 2002
```