# Deducing Inequality from an Equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, complex-numbers, recurrence-relations, functional-inequalities

I was interested in Solution of this **Non-Homogenous Recurrence Relation**

$f(n)=f(n-1) + f(n-3) + 1$

The Base conditions are:
$f(0)=1$
$f(1)=2$
$f(2)=3$

Since, the equation is **non-homogenous**, it will consists of Two Parts.

- Finding solution of `Associated Homogenous Recurrence Relation f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-3)`
  For this the **characteristic equation** will be $x^3-x^2-1=0$
  *Ideally, 3 roots should be there contributing to Solution Terms, but I am able to find only one real root. Thus, unable to find solution of Associated Homogenous Recurrence Relation.*
- Finding `Particular Solution`

It was difficult to calculate, therefore, **Using** this [**Online Calculators**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input), one can find answer by inputting
`f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-3)+1, f(0)=1, f(1)=2, f(2)=3`

The solution is quite complex. Thus, I was **interested** if we can deduce that
$f(n) \geq x^n$ for some $x\epsilon \mathbb{R} $

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First all all, let $f_n=g_n-1$ to make
$$g_n=g_{n-1}+g_{n-3} \qquad \text{with} \quad g_0=2,g_1=3,g_2=4$$
The real solution of $r^3=r^2+1$ is given by
$$r_1=\frac{1}{3} \left(1+2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{29}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$
Write
$$r^3-r^2-1=(r-r_1)(r^2+a r+b)$$ to get
$$a=\frac{2}{3} \left(\cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{29}{2}\right)\right)-1\right) \quad\text{and} \quad    b=\frac{3}{1+2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{29}{2}\right)\right)}$$ So, solving the quadratic $r^2+ar+b=0$, you have the complex roots $r_2$ and $r_3$.

Now, use the conditions to get $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ and I suppose that this will again involve a cubic equation with only one real root to generate real value of $g_n$ and $f_n$.

It could probably be easier to identify the generating function which is not very complex.

In view of the numbers $f(n) > \big[\sqrt 2\big]^n$

Comment: Thanks, the generating function is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4293564/963109) but I was more interested in inequality part. I was interested in finding x, as mentioned in last few lines of question.

Comment: @RohitSingh. $x=\sqrt 2$ may be

Comment: @RohitSingh. Confirmed and answer edited.

Comment: This answer was used in answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70481678/15845697) question.

Comment: @RohitSingh. If you look for a tighter bound, replace $\sqrt 2$ by $\sqrt{\frac{2147899}{1000000} }$. Checked up to $n=1000$